# STM32 MCU works with DEBUG but not with RUN - Reset is required with RUN

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, microcontroller, stm32cubeide

I am working on a project that was going smoothly so far until I faced the problem mentioned above lately.

**Problem/Symptoms:**

When I DEBUG the code and execute it line-by-line, it works perfectly.

When I DEBUG the code and then disconnect it from the debugger to let the code run feely, it works perfectly.

When I RUN the code runs and then gets stuck as the first encounter of HAL_Delay() or any HAL function that uses a delay. After getting stuck, as soon as I reset or power cycle the board, the code runs perfectly.

**Attempts to Fix the Issue:**

I started having this problem lately. Even when I go back to previous builds or when I create a simple “Hello World” application, the same behavior is observed (gets stuck on delay).

Some were suggesting to check the vector table and the reset handler (which I did), but if these were messed up, the MCU would not work upon reset either.

Others suggested that it may have to do with the NVIC SysTick priority having too low priority while it is called from a higher priority interrupt. So, I have disabled all unnecessary interrupts and kept the SysTick interrupt priority as follows.

[NVIC Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy0Fy.png)

MCU Option Bytes for boot address were set to the same desired address (0x 8 000 000) so that if the Boot Address line was pulled high or low it will still boot from the same address.

I am using STM32H743BIT on a custom board.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Misc things I would check: Have you verified that the system clock is running at the expected frequency? What frequency is it? Any wait states? Are you using any power saving modes? Watch dog? Are you running on top of some bootloader or using some vector table re-direction thing? Any you disabling the global interrupt mask anywhere in the code, like a "poor man's mutex" (maybe one of the ST bloat libs does that)?

Comment: Btw looking at your pic, does "Time base: system tick timer" checked mean that the ST code generator thing will generate the ISR or does it mean that Systick is now enabled and expects an ISR? What happens if you put a breakpoint inside said ISR?

Comment: most commun reason IMHO for such issues is a missing "volatile" at variables which are acessed "elsewhere" by pointers. The Code is optimized by the compiler for RELEASE and if a variable accessed with pointers from differend positions in the code is prone to be "over optimized". As a rule of thumb: if you access a variable from different positions in your code by pointer, declare it "volatile"!

Comment: First step: hotplug debugger and check why it's stuck on the HAL_Delay. Probably tick is not ticking.